# Removing Duplicates in Large Text Files

Tags: c#, permutation

I've been trying to calculate all the unique permutations for a  *very* long word (antidisestablishmentarianism), and although I can calculate the permutations for the words, I am having problems with stopping the production of duplications.

Normally I would just run the `List<T>.Contains()` method on my string, but the list of permutations becomes so large I can't keep it in memory. I made that mistake earlier and managed to use up all 8GB of memory in my computer. In order to prevent that from happening again, I changed the code to append the calculated permutation to a file and release it from memory.

My main question is this: **How can I prevent duplicate permutations from being added to my file without loading the whole thing in memory?** Is it possible to selectively load, for example, the first few megabytes, scan that, and move on until the file is completed, or should I be looking in a different direction?

This is not homework, my math homework gave a hypothetical situation where a computer could calculate 30 permutations per second and made me figure out how long it would take to calculate all the permutations. That wasn't a problem, and I don't need help with that, I just wanted to know how long it would take a modern computer to perform the same task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using an algorithm that generates all permutations **without** duplicates? That way you wouldn't have to check for them in the first place.

A Google search for "algorithm generate permutations" turns up dozens of references to get you started. e.g. [Permutation Generation Methods](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/talks/perms.pdf)